# Stylizing material buttons in Android v21

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-button, material-design, android-theme

I am trying to maintain the material design ripple effect for devices with lollipop and above (21+) and stylize the button so that it doesn't have a large margin/space around it.

**Example 1:** Buttons with ripple effect but with margin/gap:

[image: I like the ripple effect of this version, but not the gap in the layout]

**Example 2:** Buttons with NO ripple effect and without the margin/gap:

[image: I want the layout of this version, but with the ripple effect]

I want the layout of **Exmaple 2** with the ripple effect that is used in **Example 1**.

What my `styles-v21` look like for **Example 1** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

     ... other styles ...

    <style name="FacebookButton" parent="android:Widget.Material.Button">
        <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">#ff3b5998</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:borderlessButtonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless</item>


    </style>
    <style name="GoogleButton" parent="android:Widget.Material.Button">
        <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">#ffdd4b39</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:borderlessButtonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless</item>


    </style>
    <style name="TwitterButton" parent="android:Widget.Material.Button">
        <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">#ff55acee</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:borderlessButtonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless</item>


    </style>
    <style name="SkipButton" parent="android:Widget.Material.Button">
        <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">#ffdfa800</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:borderlessButtonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless</item>

    </style>

</resources>
```

What my button layout looks like for **Example 1**:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/login_with_facebook"
    android:text="@string/login_with_facebook"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/facebook_icon"
    android:drawablePadding="25dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_weight="16.88"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="45dp"
    android:theme="@style/FacebookButton" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/login_with_google"
    android:text="@string/login_with_google"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/google_icon"
    android:drawablePadding="25dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_weight="16.88"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="45dp"
    android:theme="@style/GoogleButton" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/twitter_login_button"
    android:text="@string/login_with_twitter"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/twitter_icon"
    android:drawablePadding="25dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="16.88"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:paddingLeft="45dp"
    android:theme="@style/TwitterButton" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/login_anonymously"
    android:text="@string/login_anonymously"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="50"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:theme="@style/SkipButton" />
```

Any idea how I can achieve the look of **Example 2** while using the ripple methodology I've presented? Any links to resources or help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**Extra:**
I've already read over the following

- [Coloring Buttons in Android with Material Design and AppCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519979/coloring-buttons-in-android-with-material-design-and-appcompat)
- [How to properly style material buttons in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30338852/how-to-properly-style-material-buttons-in-android)

Comment: Have you tried `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`?

Comment: @alanv this worked perfectly, thanks! Just wondering, how did you know to use that? The docs don't seem to be much help in these circumstances. 

If you post your comment as the answer I'll go ahead and vote it. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm the Android framework engineer that wrote the Material styles. ;)

Comment: @alanv random question, do you think the current style you see in example 2 is OK material design? bonus for me. haha, thanks again.

Comment: I like it more than example 1. Either is technically fine.

Comment: I just had the same problem, hope this helps!

[Material effect on button with background color](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26686433/5004910)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` to get a rectangular ripple.

Alternatively, you can create your own drawable. Here's the XML for the framework's selectable item background:

drawable/item_background_material.xml:

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <color android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Comment: Thank you! The first borderless style that worked for me! XD